# Create function by check box object name ("Dynamically")

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have multiple check boxes in a sheet, and in another sheet I have a form. When a check box is selected, then the appropriate content will be added as a column in the form sheet.

I have over 500 check boxes that's why I want to create an easy way to do this.
For example I have the following check boxes:

- Project_ID
- Project_Title
- Project_Type
- Project_Status

The object name of these check boxes start with `CB_`
so the object name of Project_Type check box is `CB_Project_Type`.

Now I created a function for each check box when it gets clicked. the function name for example is `Sub CB_Project_Type_Click()`
Then the function will check if that column exists and adds it to the form sheet.

Creating a function for all check boxes will be stupid. I want a dynamic method for it. Something like this: If "ANY" check box has been selected then, use that check box object name to add the column that has a matching name to the form sheet.

What I'm using right now is this:

```
Sub CB_Projects_Type_Click()
    CB_List "Projects_Type"
End Sub

Sub CB_List(Name As String)
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CB_" & Name).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
        For i = 0 To 99
            If IsEmpty(Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i)) Then
                Sheets("English").Columns(i + 2).Copy
                Sheets("English").Columns(i + 3).Insert
                Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = Name
                i = 99
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 0 To 99
            If Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = Name Then
                Sheets("English").Columns(i + 2).Delete
                i = 99
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

So you can see that at least I am using a single function to get that column from the check box, but I still need to create a Sub for every check box. How can I use 1 ultimate function that will get the function name from the object name?

I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your checkboxes to find the ones that are checked.

```
For Each c in ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If c.Value Then CB_List(c.Name)
Next c
```

Edit: I reread your code and I realized your problem is a little more complicated than I initially thought. In order to add the data you need and delete the data you don't need I think you need to loop through all your checkboxes every time. You can make a button that the user clicks and do something like this:

```
Sub Button1_click()
    Dim c as Checkbox
    For Each c in ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        CB_List(c.Name)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Or you might have to do:

```
Sub Button1_click()
    Dim c as OLEObject
    For Each c in ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        CB_List(c.Name)
    Next c
End Sub
```

And change this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CB_" & Name).ControlFormat.Value = 1
```

to this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Name).ControlFormat.Value = 1
```

Comment: Kyle,
It says I need 50 reputation to comment on your comment so I don't really know how to reply properly... I tried what you wrote but I get this error:
"Compile error:
Invalid outside procedure" Then I tried to define c as a checkbox but that didn't help...

Comment: @SedoSan see edit. That error simply means you have to put the code inside a Sub or Function.